# I need userIP in flutter code, but this code doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

II want to have ip i am using:

```html
import 'package:get_ip_address/get_ip_address.dart';
```

this package and i am running this function

```html
 userIp() async {
    var data = IpAddress(type: RequestType.text);
    String ip = await data.getIpAddress();
    return ip;
  }
```

it works but this is what returns me:

```html
Instance of '_Future<dynamic>'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Be sure to `await userIp()`. If you can't await (e.g. in `build`) you need to use a FutureBuilder or a stateful widget and `setState` when you get the result.

Comment: ‘import 'package:get_ip_address/get_ip_address.dart';

String main() async {
  try {
    /// Initialize Ip Address
    var ipAddress = IpAddress(type: RequestType.json);

    /// Get the IpAddress based on requestType.
    dynamic data = await ipAddress.getIpAddress();
    return data.toString();
  } on IpAddressException catch (exception) {
    /// Handle the exception.
    print(exception.message);
  }
}’

Comment: if i write async i can't String main.

Comment: you need to specify the type you're trying to get out of the method... if not, dynamic is assumed and that's a terrible practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem,

my function:

```html
  userIp() async {
    var data = IpAddress(type: RequestType.text);
    String ip = await data.getIpAddress();
    return ip;
  }
```

I call the function like this:

```html
otherfunction() async {
String ip = await userIp();
}
```